# filter_all is giving me the same dataframe unfiltered

Tags: r

Where I am trying to find only the current diagnoses and filter to any values larger than 2. I think I'm not necessarily going about this the right way but this is the line of code I have right now. With what I have written, I just returned a data frame called FU that is the exact same as FU. Not exactly sure where my issue is coming from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need `filter_at` instead of `filter_all`

```
library(dplyr)
fuKSADS_1%>% 
     select(ends_with('Current')) %>%
     filter_all(any_vars( . > 2))
```

---

Or another option is `c_across`

```
fuKSADS_1 %>%
     select(ends_with('Current')) %>%
     rowwise %>% 
     filter(any(c_across(everything()) > 2)) %>%
     ungroup
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `Reduce`

```
i1 <- endsWith(names(fuKSADS_1), 'Current')
subset(fuKSADS_1[i1], Reduce(`|`, lapply(fuKSADS_1[i1], `>`, 2)))
```

Comment: @AlexSmith you just need to subset the columns.  I updated the post

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can use `rowSums` on columns that end with `"Current"` :

```
cols <- grep('Current$', names(fukSADS_1))
result <- fukSADS_1[rowSums(fukSADS_1[cols] > 2) > 0, cols]
```